# Text Files (or URL) Manipulation With Certain Conditions

Tags: java

I've recently started a small project whose aim is to do the following with two lists found in two separate (and local) txt files (I will provide more details about these lists below):

- Read and evaluate the info on list #1—which contains several, simple forms with 3-4 elements such as name, timezone, and category—and take the values of two of these (timezone and category) and use them to make a comparison with the same values located on list #2, and if there's a match between two users in these two groups of compared values, have the program output the result using the format "Name1 | Name2".

To further elaborate on this -- what I'm working with here is a tutoring program, where list #1 contains certain information about a number of apprentices, and list #2 has the same type of data but for tutors. Both look like this (example):

**Name:** Anabel 
**Timezone:** EST (or it can be UCT / PST) 
**Category:** A1, B1, C1 (this is what the apprentice requires to learn about)

So, essentially, I want to be able to have my program (1) read a first txt file containing the apprentices' applications, (2) evaluate the Timezone and Category fields, (3) compare their value with that of those found in the same fields located inside a second txt file containing the tutor profiles, (4) if there's a match in timezones and at least in one learning category, (5) write to a new txt file the tutor name followed by the apprentice name using a pipe sign ("|") to divide both. In words, the end result is: "tutor X has been paired with apprentice Y".

Now, I have some experience in Java and I know how to read, write and search txt files using common classes found in the java.util.Scanner and java.io packages, but I don't know how to go about making the comparison described above between these two txt files and get the desired output. I've also searched the site for things that could help me do this, but unfortunately I haven't had much luck, so I was hoping I could get some open help here from people who are real experts at Java programming.

---

Additional information:

- The main info for this project (apprentices and tutor lists) I have extracted manually from two separate forum threads, and I've thought it'd probably be easier to just have my program access the URL for these two threads and work from there by collecting the same data it would otherwise extract from the txt files. If I were to go this route, I'd feel happy using the Jsoup library as I am familiar with CSS- and jQuery-like selectors as well as HTML, but once selected the elements I want to work with I'd be stuck again in not knowing how to do the comparison with the info pulled from both locations and generate the result.
- This tutor-apprentice assignment process would be done once per month, and the overall amount of apprentices whom sign up each round is something like ~60 people; the sign-up application also follows the format I showed a few paragraphs above.

*Any* help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to define classes like `Tutor` and `Student`, make two lists from your files/url, and run some compare. As for compare func, well, it implementation shouldn't be very complicated.

Example (I'm lazy, so I'll use one class;] also, add appropriate modifiers ):

```java
abstract class Person {
    String name;
    String timezone;
    Set<String> categories;

    /** Return number of categories matched with given Person */
    int match(Person person){
        if(person == null || !person.timezone.equals(this.timezone))
            return 0;
        Set<String> intersection = new HashSet<String>(this.categories);
        intersection.retainAll(person.categories);
        return intersection.size();
    }

    Person bestMatch(List<Person> persons){
        if(persons==null || persons.isEmpty())
            return null;
        int maxMatch = 0;
        int matchedPerson = null;
        for(Person person : persons){
            int m = match(person);
            if(m > maxMatch){
                maxMatch = m;
                matchedPerson = person;
            }
        }
        return matchedPerson;
    }
}
```

example usage:

```
List<Person> tutors = gatherTutors();
List<Person> students = gatherStudents();

for(Person student : students){
    Person tutor = student.bestMatch(tutors);
    if(tutor!=null)
        System.out.println("tutor "+tutor.name+" has been paired with apprentice "+student.name);
}
```

Of course, you could make it more acurate, or more balanced - for example, if best match is found, remove tutor from list, and sort students by categories number before matching.